# Transferring creation date from one file to another

Tags: bash, touch, osx-mountain-lion, stat, filemtime

I have been trying without success to transfer the creation date from one file to another on OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion) using Bash. It’s probably some combination of `stat` and `touch` but I haven’t quite figured it out, because the format used by stat does not match that needed by touch.

This is what I tried so far. It’s part of a video conversion script which obliterates the creation date:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    # convert video
    HandBrakeCLI -i "$f" -o "/Users/J/Desktop/$(basename $f .AVI).mp4" -e x264 -q 20 -B 160

    # read out creation date from source file
    date_transfer=$(stat -f "%Sm" "$f")     # output e.g.: Oct 27 16:33:41 2013

    # write creation date of source to converted file
    touch -t $date_transfer /Users/J/Desktop/$(basename $f .AVI).mp4  # requires 201310271633 instead
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversion of time format could be done via `date` utility:

On Linux (GNU coreutils):

```
$ date -d 'Oct 27 16:33:41 2013' '+%Y%m%d%H%M'
201310271633
```

On OS X ([`date` options](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/date.1.html) taken from [Darwin](http://support.apple.com/kb/ta25634) manpages available online):

```
$ date -j -f '%b %d %T %Y' 'Oct 27 16:33:41 2013' '+%Y%m%d%H%M'
201310271633
```

Your code should look like this (on OS X):

```
for f in "$@"
do
   # convert video
   HandBrakeCLI -i "$f" -o "/Users/J/Desktop/$(basename "$f" .AVI).mp4" -e x264 -q 20 -B 160

   # read out creation date from source file
   date_transfer=$(stat -f '%Sm' "$f")

   # write creation date of source to converted file
   touch -t $(date -j -f '%b %d %T %Y' "$date_transfer" '+%Y%m%d%H%M') /Users/J/Desktop/$(basename "$f" .AVI).mp4
done
```

Notice the quotes around `$date_transfer`. Date wants to get the date as one parameter and shell would split parts of `date_transfer` at spaces if the quotes were not present.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to fight date formatting: use `touch -r refFile fileToBeChanged`

Your code would look like:

```
for f in "$@"
do
   # convert video
   HandBrakeCLI -i "$f" -o "/Users/J/Desktop/$(basename $f .AVI).mp4" -e x264 -q 20 -B 160

   # transfer creation date of source to converted file
   touch -r "$f" /Users/J/Desktop/$(basename $f .AVI).mp4
done
```

Comment: Hi Glenn, well spotted. This makes the script much simpler and circumvents the messy date conversion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try: date -d`$date_transfer` +%Y%m%d%H%M

> `formatted_date=$(date -d$date_transfer +%Y%m%d%H%M)`
>
> `touch -t $formatted_date /Users/J/Desktop/$(basename $f .AVI).mp4`

Comment: This will not work on OS X, due to differencies in `date` utility options. I have already provided a more complete answer.